# Why won't links within Gmail open in new tabs anymore?

Tags: firefox, gmail

I recently upgraded to Firefox 3.6 and all of a sudden, clicking on links within email messages open in the same window. They used to open in a new tab using Firefox. In fact, this is still the case when using Chrome or IE7.

I can't find any settings that might be causing this behavior. I even looked at my add ins and extensions.

Thoughts?

Comment: This question **is** computer related. The issue is related to his Firefox, not to GMail in particular. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Question re-opened.  I agree with Gnoupi that this is a firefox issue and gmail just happens to be what he is using within it.

Comment: So does it still happen with a blank profile and extensions disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me in Firefox 3.6.
The links in my GMail emails (which are displayed in HTML of course) are like

```
<href="http://..." target="_blank">
```

...and the `target="_blank"`means they *should* be opening in a new tab or a new window.
Possibly you have some extension which is changing the way this works.

Try running Firefox without extensions

```
firefox.exe -safe-mode
```

or with a completely new profile

```
firefox.exe -P some_new_profile
```

and see if the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Using Firefox here, just notice if I right-click an email I wish to reply to and then choose "Send link..." from the contextual menu, it opens the email in a new tab.  Not as easy as it could be, but functional.

Answer (score 1):

I had been suffering from the same problem. Toying around with plugins, I realize that the 'Tabs open relative' plugin, which had to be manually installed in earlier versions of Firefox (but now seems to be there by default) is the culprit.

Disabling it, fixes the problem and all links marked with

```
{target="_blank"}
```

(including the ones on GMail) do open in new tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Preferences->Applications`, and find the *`mailto`* Content Type.  Change this to an application that changes the tab behavior.